# How to find caret position in WPF combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, caret

Since WPF Combobox does not have CaretIndex property like Textbox and SelectionStart property in C#, I wonder how to get caret index of my WPF Combobox control?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Its not directly accesible althoug you can get it from its child control. You need to get at the PART_EditableTextBox control from the combo box's control template. The easiest way to do this would be to override OnApplyTemplate in a derivation of ComboBox and then use that derivation to subscribe to selection changed. Then you can get the CaretIndex

```
protected void override OnApplyTemplate()
{
    var myTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
    if (myTextBox != null)
    {
      myTextBox .SelectionChanged += OnDropSelectionChanged;
    }
}

private void OnDropSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var textbox = sender as TextBox;
   if (textbox != null)
    {
      //you can write your own logic.
      _carentIndex = textbox.CaretIndex;
    }
}
```

Make sure you unscubscribe to SelectionChanged in your dispose or appropriate place

```
myTextBox .SelectionChanged -= OnDropSelectionChanged;
```

Comment: I don't get the part "in a derivation of ComboBox". Can you explain it to me? Besides, I still don't know how those two methods **link** to my Combobox control. Thanks.